# Is this causal effect identifiable? It includes a mixture of observational and interventional data with selection effects

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables

The `DAG` of the model is below. We wish to estimate `P(attitude | do(exposed))`.

moving up from the bottom of the dag:

- we observe a `measure` which comes from a survey instrument.

  - `observed` influences *who* takes the survey
  - `attitude` is their underlying attitude that we really care about
- `attitude` is influenced by

  - whether or not they `clicked` (viewed an ad)
  - original `lat`ent variables that encapsulate their prior beliefs/values/etc
- `clicked` is a function of:

  - whether or not they were `exposed` to the ad
  - their `lat`ent variables
- `exposed` is a function of:

  - an `algo`rithm that we cannot observe the internals of
  - our `targeting` criteria (that we can control)
- the `algo` also influences whether or not they are `observed` in the survey data
- their `lat`ent variables are influenced by `dem`ographic variables

Most variables are not observed:

- everything that is a rectangle is observable

  - `targeting`, `dem`, and `measure`
- everything that is an ellipse is unobservable (everything else)
- special case: `exposed` is partially observable (we can measure `P(exposed | targeting)` but we won't have `exposed` at the individual level

In principle, `targeting` is an instrumental variable for `attitude`, but we cannot observe `attitude` directly, since there is a selection variable (`observed`).

I have tried to use the [`causaleffect`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/vignettes/causaleffect.pdf) package in `R`, but I am unsure how to account for unobserved variables using that package.

I have the vague notions that:

- since `targeting` can only influence `attitude` through its effect on `exposed` it can be used as an instrumental variable
- if we manipulate `targeting`, changes in `measure` will only be due to changes in `attitude`

I think this may also be related to the notion of [transportability](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r404-reprint.pdf), but I am a bit lost on how to incorporate that.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Model DAG]

Comment: This isn't a full answer to the DAG, but just a subset of your question. Have you tried using the "set.edge.attribute" command in the *causaleffect* package? With the "set.edge.attribute" command, you can tell the package which edges are unobserved. See page 2 of this link for reference: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/causaleffect/causaleffect.pdf. Hope that helps. I also want to confirm what the causal effect you are trying to estimate is. Is it the effect of exposure to an ad on attitude, which you are proxying with some measure?

Comment: What exactly does "observed" stand for? Is it the case that people select into the survey, so that "observed" stands for "sample selection"?

Comment: @LandonGibson 

I have tried using the `set.edge.attribute` command in `causaleffect`, and what i couldn't figure out is that that sets the property of an _edge_, not of a _node_. I was trying to figure how to set _nodes_ as latent. A closer reading of the paper accompanying the package shows that it only works with "semi-markovian" DAGs, where each latent variable has exactly two children — so the package uses this way of encoding latent variables — the latent variable is never explicitly referred to in the DAG you feed into `causaleffect`. But my DAG is not semi-markovian :/

Comment: @LandonGibson 

To this:

"I also want to confirm what the causal effect you are trying to estimate is. Is it the effect of exposure to an ad on attitude, which you are proxying with some measure?"

Yes, exactly. We care about the effect of an exposure of an ad on an attitude, but we can only measure it via survey — but there is selection bias via `observed`

Comment: @JulianSchuessler you're right — `observed` is just a binary variable encoding the selection bias. If `observed = 0`, we don't get to measure their attitude at all. Forgive me if this is not the correct way to encode for selecting variables in a DAG! I wasn't sure if this was right or if there was some other notation.

Comment: @Tom, thanks for clarifying. I think that there are some issues with the way you've presented this DAG. First, your treatment (exposure) should be observable; otherwise, you can't estimate an effect! Secondly, what exactly is algo? Is it something that decides whether or not someone sees an ad (A/B testing)? Why does it influence whether or not you see information on an individual? Why is algo a function of latent demographic variables? Thanks, sorry for the barrage of questions.

Comment: @LandonGibson you can estimate an intent-to-treat model without knowing if someone was actually treated, which this would be. But my notation was wrong, and [this paper](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r445.pdf) actually explained everything that I was wondering. Algo in this case is the Facebook algorithm, and it influences whether or not the survey would be shown to someone. And latent characteristics will drive the FB algo.